# What Russian poet to recommend for beginners and intermediate learners?

Tags: обучение, литература

What Russian poet could be recommender for reading for beginners and intermediate Russian Language learners?

Poetry has opinion to be difficult for learners because of extended vocabulary and many neologisms. But some of the poets have written in the way easier to understand.

What poet would you recommend for person that is learning Russian and is not yet very advanced as appropriate for his/hers language level?

Comment: You're looking for a poet that uses simple vocabulary and simple language constructs? Isn't that kind of an oxymoron? :)

Comment: Pushkin made contemporary language usage in poetry a-ok. Before him poetry was dusty, stuffy and incomprehensible. He's also "our everything", give him a go.

Comment: +1 for Pushkin. You can try to compare different English translations of 'Yevgeniy Onegin' with the original and with each other and, in this way, to understand the novel better.

Comment: Pushkin, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the poetry of [Sergei Yesenin](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (Сергей Есенин). Very beautiful, clean language. Truly Russian spirit.